# using MS windows server 2003R2 as a VS2008 dev machine

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008

At my work im required to used Windows 2003 service pack 2 as my VS 2008 development environment running on a intel quad core PC. Intel 920 @ 2.67Ghz , 12 gig ram

Does anyone have any info on how to tweak the OS to optimize software dev on such a machine.

I get numerous problems, such as (for developing C# asp.net 2.0 apps and winforms applications

1. unexplained IDE environment lockups and crashes
2. Cant auto geenrate datasets in ASP.net, IDe locks up
3. screen corupption and what seem to be lack of resource issues when 2 instances of VS 2008 open with projects.
4. Extensive delays in gettting source code from network source control box.

MY dev manager says its network issues and the IT say theres nothing wrong on the network and such and its the computer and neither can diagnose where the problem lies.

I would appreciate any advice or suggesstions, im ready to hand in my notice in sheer frustration at simply trying to get a stable work enviroment

Comment: BTW, tell your manager to use Windows 7 instead - either Professional or Enterprise - client OS with a lot of the same server features as Windows Server 2003.

Comment: Guaranteed the problem does *not* lie with Server 2003. I've run it for years on my workstation, and I still have it on a couple of laptops. It's rock solid with Visual Studio and everything else. You might need to reload your computer, but most of that *does* sound suspiciously like network issues to me... And I ain't just a dev manager: I spent plenty of time doing IT ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There's a great guide to using your WS2003 machine as a workstation at http://win2k3.msfn.org/, I've used WS2003 (as well as 2008 and 2008 R2) as a workstation for years, and it's quite doable.

Comment: While a decent resource, the "guide" is mostly concerned with superficial elements. A computer is perfectly usable (at least for development, maybe not gaming) without DirectX and Themes. I for one prefer some of these pieces of Server OS's, though I agree that the Shutdown Tracker is slightly annoying. Either way, the steps presented in the guide won't fix his network issues and lock-up problems.